# jQuery tools custom validator - matcher won't match

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-tools

I'm using the [jquery tools validator](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/validator/). I created some custom validators, e.g.:

```
$.tools.validator.fn('input.emailNotReq', function(el, v) {
  if (el.val() !== '') {
    return mailRegExp.test(el.val());
  }
  else {
    return true;
  }
});


$.tools.validator.fn('input.checked', function(el, v) {
  return el.is(':checked') ? true : false;
});
```

Here is some example html:

```
<input class="checked" id="txreg_checkboni" type="checkbox"
 name="tx_stwregistration_reg[processes][process][acceptBoniCheck]" value="1">

<input class="emailNotReq" id="txreg_email" type="text"
 name="tx_stwregistration_reg[processes][process][customer][email]">
```

Now, in the chromium developer tools, I set breakepoints in both validators. The first works just fine. The second seems to not find any element with the given selector. At least it doesn't stop at the breakepoint. But there definitely is an element matching the selector, because I can get it through a watch expression. Does anyone see syntax errors or has another idea what could be wrong?

This is the start script:

```
$('#swRegistrationForm form').validator({
  lang: 'en',
  position: 'top center',
  messageClass: 'formValidationError',
  offset: [10, -0],
  message: '<div><em/></div>'
});
```

Comment: I found out that apparently the problem is a hidden input field with the same name attribute than the checkbox input field. The validator doesn't even care about the input after the hidden one.